# jquery remove all classes from class

Tags: jquery

How can I remove all classes from a class but keep the original class?

html

```
<div class="document-wrapper removeme1 removeme2 removeme3"></div>
```

jquery

```
$('.document-wrapper').removeClass();
```

end with this

```
<div class="document-wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$('.document-wrapper').removeClass().addClass('document-wrapper');`

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
$('.document-wrapper').removeClass().addClass('document-wrapper');
```

Comment: there is no id in the element

Comment: you somehow need to know which element are you using

Comment: or you can remove all calssess from all elements with that class.

Comment: my post is older then yours :(

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite the `class` attribute :

```
$('.document-wrapper').attr('class', 'document-wrapper');
```

this will replace the current `class` value with just 'document-wrapper'

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('.document-wrapper').removeAttr('class').addClass('document-wrapper');
```

[**check this out in fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/FsUCg/)

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the `className` property of the underlying DOM element.

```
$('.document-wrapper')[0].className = "document-wrapper";
```